# How break queue process in dispatch_async iOS Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, break, dispatch-async

In my simple code,I want break process in queue global if condition x == 2 and go to main queue.

How to proceed for this ?

Dario Basso Cardoso

```
var x = 1 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW,0)) {
    x++

    if x == 2 {
        break // error in this part or
        return // does not work well
    }

    // more codes...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {  () -> Void in 
        // execute the main code
        // with break or not
        if x == 2 {
            // verified that break
        }

        // next codes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to explicitly exit your process, once the program reaches the end of your async process it will exit by itself.

You need to think of it the other way around. Keep the process going for as long as there is something to compute, then let it run out

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW,0))     {
   while x < 2 {
    x++
   }

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {  () -> Void in {
    ...
   }
}
```